# How to use dateSetAction() and dismissedAction() methods in DatePickerAndroid?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid#datesetaction) is not enough to understand nor there is any example to understand. Why & how to use `dateSetAction()` and `dismissedAction()` methods in `DatePickerAndroid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are basically internal `getter` functions/methods that are called internally to determine whether the `date` has been selected or not. These two methods are defined in the `DatePickerAndroid` class as:

```
 static get dateSetAction() {
   return 'dateSetAction';
 }

 static get dismissedAction() {
   return 'dismissedAction';
 }
```

You can visit [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/DatePickerAndroid/DatePickerAndroid.android.js) page to populate yourself about these methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple explanation:**

`dateSetAction` is a type of action that tells you the date has been selected in the datepicker.

`dismissedAction` is also another type of action that tells you the datepicker dialog has been dismissed/closed.

**Example:**

```
async openAndroidDatePicker() { 
   try {
     const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
       date: new Date(2020, 4, 25)
     });
     if (action === DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
         console.log('Date picker has been dismissed/closed');
     } else if (action === DatePickerAndroid.dateSetAction) {
         console.log('Date has been selected');
     }
    } catch ({code, message}) {
      console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user picked a date, Object containing action, year, month (0-11), day. If the user dismissed the dialog, the Promise will still be resolved with the action being **DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction** and all the other keys being undefined. Always check whether the action before reading the values.

```
  async openAndroidDatePicker() { 
  try {
  const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
    // Use `new Date()` for current date.
    // May 25 2020. Month 0 is January.
    date: new Date(2020, 4, 25)
  });
  if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
    // Selected year, month (0-11), day
  }
} catch ({code, message}) {
  console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy & past. I know about the `action` property but i am asking about the `dateSetAction()` and `dismissedAction()`.